# Showing Tooltips for a CButton in disabled state

Tags: c++, oop, mfc, tooltip

I have a CButton instance (say `m_Button1`) and I have a CTooltipCtrl instance (say `m_TooltipButton1`). The following code works to display a tooltip "**Button Enabled**" when the button is in active state.

```
CButton m_Button1;
CToolTipCtrl m_TooltipButton1;

BOOL TestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  ...

    if (m_TooltipButton1.Create(this)) {
        m_TooltipButton1.AddTool(GetDlgItem(m_Button1.GetDlgCtrlID()), _T("Button Enabled"));
        m_Button1.EnableToolTips(TRUE);
        m_TooltipButton1.Activate(TRUE);
    }
  ...
  ...
}

BOOL TestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    m_TooltipButton1.RelayEvent(pMsg);
    return SubDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

I am looking for a way to display a tooltip which says "**Button Disabled**" when the button is in disabled state and not accepting any mouseover and click events.
I tried using the `ON_NOTIFY_EX` event with `TTN_NEEDTEXT` but again, the method gets triggered only when the button is in active state.

How can the desired functionality be achieved ?

Comment: AFAIK, tooltips attached to a control do not work when the control is disabled. Display a separate tooltip window that is not attached to the control itself.

Comment: @IInspectable ?

Comment: Following general guidelines from [this page](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tooltipcontrols/article.php/c2277/Tooltip-for-disabled-controls.htm) made it work.
I did have to write some code to adjust the behavior when mouse was moved within the bounds of the disabled control